# How to create a global plugin in React?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, plugins, mixins

VueJS supports global plugins with the ability to use a mixin that can be applied to every component life-cycle. For example, every time a component renders I could log "Hello Dave" without even touching any existing components in an application.

**Has anyone attempted anything similar in React?**

> Note: I know mixins are bad and I'm not generally advocating for them here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly approach I've just cooked up. I'm essentially hijacking the React.createElement function:

```js
let origCreateElement = React.createElement;

React.createElement = function (element, props, ...children) {
  if (typeof element.metaData !== 'undefined') {
    return origCreateElement.apply(React, [function (...rest) {
      let origElementOutput = element.apply(React, [...rest]);

      console.log(element.metaData);

      // **** To access Parent/Ancestors ****
      // React.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentOwner.current.type = element; 
      // React.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentOwner.current.return.type

      return origElementOutput;
    }, props, ...children]);
  }

  return origCreateElement.apply(React, [element, props, ...children]);
};

function Hello({name}) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ 
    first: name, last: 'Doe',
  });
  
  Hello.metaData = state;
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setState({first: 'Dave', last: 'Dave'});
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Hello { state.first }
    </div>
  );
}

Hello.metaData = null;

ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="John" />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This generally serves no good purpose because in your app you'll use transpilation and modules most times and so able to execute proper ways to do that, which is replacing React imports with your own wrapper that can do any magic you need. Also you probably won't be able to patch `*` React imports. It's a mistake to patch createElement to add side effects to render, they often correlate but certainly not always. You can render without creating new elements, and you can create new elements without rendering them. For this purpose you're more likely need to dig into React renderer

Comment: @EstusFlask Actually you can import the hijack first before React at the entry point of your application and if you are using a single React version (using an approach in Webpack or some bundler) you'll get the hijack in every module. It doesn't affect the render cycle. And the purpose here was not to do a meaningless render, but for example, to track stuff when things are actually rendering.

Comment: BTW, I'm not necessarily sanctioning this approach. I'm just doing an ugly hack for something I feel is missing in React. The ability to "plugin" to React for some few horizontal-slice needs would be handy. I might post a link to this question in the official React Github and see if there's any traction there.

Comment: If you're in modular environment, you can swap react module at Webpack level or specify custom createElement function in Babel without mangling any existing package.  Yes, it's a hack. As I said, it tracks elements and not things that are rendered. A proper approach is to hook into React renderer, can be custom renderer or a wrapper, or use devtools protocol, as I remember, it's doable this way. Any way, thanks for sharing

Comment: @EstusFlask when you say "tracks elements", you mean because I'm only patching `createElement`. Yeah, totally get that, but for my use case that was good enough. Definitely worth looking into hijacking the react renderer, but feel free to post an answer/experiment regarding that. Thanks for the feedback!